# Inductive Proof With Regular Expression

Tags: induction, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm trying to prove that the elements of the language $L((01+10)(01+10)^*)$ have an equal number of $0$'s and $1$'s.
So far I've the base case: $R^n \to R^0 = 01 + 10$, all of which have equal number of $0$'s and $1$'s.
I'm just not sure how to proceed for $R^{(n+1)}$...
I've tried to simplify the expression in order to get somehow $2n$ in $10$ or $01$ but I can find a way to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't the base case merely 01+10? And I suppose you want to do *structural* induction?

Comment: It's a simpler option... Thanks, I think I'll use that instead. But I don't think it makes much of a difference though, I still don't know what to do next... Yes, I was trying to do a structural induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible way to solve your question. Given a word $u$, let $|u|_0$ (respectively $|u|_1$) denote the number of occurrences of $0$ (respectively $1$) in $u$. Now consider the map $f: \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by
$$
f(u) = |u|_0 - |u|_1
$$
Observe that $u$ has an equal number of $0$'s and $1$'s if and only if $f(u) = 0$.
Now here are the steps to conclude:

1. Verify that $f(01) = f(10) = 0$
2. Verify that $f(uv) = f(u) + f(v)$ and more generally, that $f(u_1 \cdots u_n) = f(u_1) + \dotsm + f(u_n)$
3. Use (2) to show that for every word $u \in \{01, 10\}^+$, $f(u) = 0$.
4. Conclude.